# Did Thomas Pearne do anything other than contradict Granville Sharp?

Tags: church-history, arianism

Granville Sharp (1735 - 1813) [see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granville_Sharp) is famous for his stoical labours in eradicating slavery and for his energetic achievement in re-patriating former slaves to Sierra Leone. Although he has a memorial in Westminster Abbey, I would suggest that he also well deserves a statue to himself in Bristol. (And I am informed that there is now a [vacant space](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-bristol-53004748) for one in that city).

Above and beyond such admirable exploits, Granville Sharp found the time and the energy to write numerous books on Christian matters, notably his studiously researched book on the Greek article and how an understanding of its use is necessary to properly appreciate passages of the bible that refer to the Deity of Jesus Christ.

His findings on the subject are commonly called [Sharp's Rule](https://www.theopedia.com/granville-sharps-rule).

This labour of love was fiercely opposed by one Thomas Pearne who deliberately hid behind the pseudonym 'Gregory Blunt' - an obvious mockery of the name of the noble Granville Sharp.

I have been attempting to research Thomas Pearne and I would have liked to make a link to Wikipedia, but I cannot find anything to link to. In fact I can find nothing - anywhere - about Thomas Pearne. He appears (to me, at the present time) to have left no footprint on earth other than in the guise of 'Gregory Blunt' and his adversarial writings against the good Granville.

Can anyone point me in the direction of any worthy achievements or any documents worth reading, other than the contradictory communications made against Sharp, under the blunt pseudonym, which caused the good Granville to have to laboriously answer, publicly, on the behalf of his own researched findings ?

---

EDIT : See @Lesley 's comment below which indicates at least six letters were sent to Granville Sharp by Thomas Pearne, under the pseudonym 'Gregory Blunt', every single one of them being adversarial.

Comment: Looks like these 6 letters are co-authored by Georg Kaplin and posted under that name as recently as 2019.  I wonder if they have been co-opted.  http://www.theologyweb.com/campus/member.php?1965-George-Kaplin&tab=aboutme

Comment: Do you refer to Thomas Pearne, of Peterhouse, Cambridge (c. 1753-1827)  B.A. 1777, M.A. 1780, Fellow at Cambridge and author of “Six More Letters to Granville Sharp, Esq., on his Remarks upon the Uses of the Article in the Greek Testament"?

Comment: I thought you were referring to a user of that name here, I didn't know there was a historical figure.

Comment: @Lesley Yes, indeed. That is the person. I recently acquired Granville Sharp's excellent work on the Greek article and thus was prompted my question.

Comment: @curiousdannii Yes, the name 'Gregory Blunt' is more well known, historically. The name 'Thomas Pearne' is not so prominent or well recognised.

Comment: @NigelJ Well I guess one answer is that he inspired at least one follower enough to even adopt his name...

Comment: @curiousdannii  me too I was about to vtc   Lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thomas Pearne, of Peterhouse, Cambridge, was also a Shakespeare critic.

> The article explores the criticism of William Shakespeare by Thomas Pearne in his book review of "Shakespeare," edited by Issac Reed and published in 1785. The review was originally serialized in the 1786 British periodical the "Monthly Review." The author compares Pearne's comments with the editorial glosses which appear in the 1974 edition of "The Riverside Shakespeare."
>   Source: http://pdc-connection.ebscohost.com/c/literary-criticism/34685030/thomas-pearne-peterhouse-cambridge-shakespeare-critic

It seems that Gregory Blunt is the pseudonym of Thomas Pearne:

> Gregory Blunt: Pseudonym of Thomas Pearne, of Peterhouse, Cambridge (c. 1753-1827)  B.A.  1777, M.A. 1780, Fellow at Cambridge and a good classical scholar.  Author of “Six More Letters to Granville Sharp, Esq., on his Remarks upon the Uses of the Article in the Greek Testament. London: J. Johnston, 1803”  Address: https://drgregoryblunt.wordpress.com/
>   Source: https://independent.academia.edu/BluntGregory

Whether the work of Thomas Pearne (with regard to Shakespeare) is considered worthy, I could not say.  That academic stuff is out of my league and well above my pay grade.

Comment: So gratifying that these dons who have been dead for 200 years took the time to leave us with wordpress sites!

Comment: As @Peter Turner hints, your Academia link is clearly to a modern author (papers are all dated 2017 onwards). It is not a link to Thomas Pearne 1753-1827. But up-voted and accepted, nevertheless.

Comment: Pretty sure Georg Kaplin republished the 6 letters as co-author in 2019.  Hence the appearance on Wordpress.